# Multiple Inheritance - want to extend a class that extends Panel, but I also want to extend StackPanel

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a control, ShrinkingTabPanel, that proportionally resizes tabs as they're added so they all fit (like Chrome). However, it extends Panel, and this doesn't work with the functionality I'm trying to achieve - the width of the ShrinkingTabPanel doesn't increase with number of items like it should.

When I changed the class to extend StackPanel instead, that was the exact functionality I needed.

However, ShrinkingTabPanel is a control that is part of a library that we bought, and it's usually discouraged to change imported source code.

I know multiple inheritance isn't allowed in C#, but is there any way I can "effectively" extend ShrinkingTabPanel and StackPanel in one class?

The first solution I thought of was to make a new class that extended StackPanel, and to just call ShrinkingTabPanel.ArrangeOverride() and ShrinkingTabPanel.MeasureOverride() within the respective methods, effectively extending ShrinkingTabPanel. But I'm not sure if that's the smartest idea.

Comment: What about creating a new Panel that inherits from StackPanel, and copying the relevant code from ShrinkingTabPanel? That way you keep the old ShrinkingTabPanel untouched and create your own Panel that behaves how you want.

Comment: Maybe this article on the subject can give you a way to figure it out. Although I think that what almulo says is a good way to go. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10072/Simulated-Multiple-Inheritance-Pattern-for-C